# Sharedpreferences clears only partially

Tags: android

I am trying to load the last open activity after the app is closed. The below code does that. Now i try to reset on button click so that it clears the sharedpref file and go back to the mainactivity. But clear() method clears only the values that is passed from mainactivity and does not clear the lastactivity key value from the preference file.So when the reset button is clicked the app freezes with a white screen.Tried to remove() the individual lastactivity key value alone but did not work. Also tried apply() ,instead of using commit().What i am doing wrong.

EDIT: I removed the `finish()` method and passed `intent` to `mainactivity` class. Now on reset click the white screen freeze is gone and loads `mainactivity`. But still the `lastactivity` value is not removed from preferences file. Now after force close and on opening app, it loads `secondactivity` with `defaultName` as values instead of loading `mainactivity`.

SecondActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

TextView textView1  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView1.setText("Spinner 1");
TextView textView2  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
textView2.setText("Spinner 2");

SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(Dispatcher.PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
       spinnerValue = prefs.getString("spinnerValue", "defaultName");
       spinnerValue2 = prefs.getString("spinnerValue2", "defaultName");

TextView textView5  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
       textView5.setText(spinnerValue);       
TextView textView6  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
       textView6.setText(spinnerValue2);  

Button resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.end);
resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        finish();
        clear();

      }

    });
  }

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(Dispatcher.PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("lastActivity", getClass().getName());
    editor.commit();
}

public void clear(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(Dispatcher.PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    //editor.remove("lastActivity");
    //editor.commit(); 

    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}
}
```

Update:

```
     boolean donotexecutecode = true;

@Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
            donotexecutecode = false;
              clear();
              finish();
          }
    @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(Dispatcher.PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            if (donotexecutecode) {
            Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("lastActivity", getClass().getName());
            editor.commit();
            }
                return;
            }
    public void clear(){
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(Dispatcher.PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.clear(); 
        editor.commit(); 
    }
```

Comment: What was the problem with remove? Its working perfectly for me.

Comment: on click, second activity closes and a white screen appears and freezes

Comment: Try to change the sequence : finish();
        clear(); to clear(); finish();

Comment: Already tried those options.

Comment: Then could you please attach your logcat?

Comment: Did not find any entries related to it. Its very long. I should attach whole log?

Comment: Apparently onPause() is called after clear(). So you always put that key. You should use a boolean flag to not execute the code in onPause if you want to force a finish.

Comment: @greenapps Please show me how to do that.

Comment: private boolean donotexecutecode = false; donotexecutecode = true; if (donotexecutecode) return; Three statements. Place every statement in a different place in your code.

Comment: Okay I will try now.

Comment: @greenapps I did like this. declared boolean donotexecutecode = true; in class. then donotexecutecode = false; inside click method and if(donotexecutecode) return inside onPause(); it works now. is it right? i interchanged boolean value from your comment.

Comment: Well if it works then it is most probably allrigth. You are the one to judge i think. I do not understand what uou mean by interchancged sentence.

Comment: Sorry.. I now see what you mean. No wrong of course. That can never work.

Comment: Its okay. Is there any other way to do this other than boolean? anyways i will accept your answer. i am glad you made me do it.

Comment: Please adapt your code here so we better know what you did.

Comment: I have updated. Is there any other way to do this other than boolean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `onPause()`  is called after `clear();`. So you always put that key. You should use a boolean flag to not execute the code in onPause if you want to force a `finish()`.

Answer (score 0):

try the SharedPreferences.Editor instead of only Editor.

Comment: That make no difference if it is imported by _SharedPreferences.Editor_